# Showing Hidden Image With Onclick Function

Tags: javascript, html, button, visibility, hidden

my objective is to have an image hidden until a button is pressed to then show the previously hidden image.

Right now I have an image in html with an Id of "yellowrose" that is hidden with this code:

```
    <div id="yellowrose"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/ppfhZa6.jpg" style="visibility:hidden"></div>
```

In JS I have several things happening with the buttonx.onclick, but I can't seem to make the image visible. Here's my JS code:

```
    var content = document.getElementById("content");
var buttonx = document.getElementById("show-more");
let yellowrose = document.getElementById("yellowrose");


window.onload = function(){
    
buttonx.onclick = function () {
    document.getElementById("yellowrose").style.visibility="visible";
          if(content.className == "open") {
              //shrink the box
              content.className = "";
              buttonx.innerHTML = "Continue to the Sunlit Pavillion?";
          } else{
              //expand the box
              content.className = "open";
              buttonx.innerHTML = "As you wander through the garden grounds you notice a striking Yellow Rose";
              
          }

          }
        }
```

Do you have any suggestions on how I can make the "yellowrose" image visible through the buttonx.onclick function? Thank you.

Comment: Please move your `style="visibility:hidden"` in the **img** tag to your `<div id="yellowrose">` as your JavaScript is targeted to `yellowrose` which is **div** tag not **img** tag.

Answer (score 0):

An `id` cannot contain a space.

As per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id):

> `id`'s **value must not contain whitespace (spaces, tabs etc.)**. Browsers treat non-conforming IDs that contain whitespace as if the whitespace is part of the ID. In contrast to the [class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes#attr-class) attribute, which allows space-separated values, elements can only have one single ID value.

Additionally, you are setting the `visibility` of `#yellowrose`, the **container** of the image, and not the image itself. To solve this, simply get the `firstChild` property:

```js
var content = document.getElementById("content");
var buttonx = document.getElementById("showmore");
let yellowrose = document.getElementById("yellowrose");


window.onload = function() {

  buttonx.onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById("yellowrose").firstChild.style.visibility = "visible";
    if (content.className == "open") {
      //shrink the box
      content.className = "";
      buttonx.innerHTML = "Continue to the Sunlit Pavillion?";
    } else {
      //expand the box
      content.className = "open";
      buttonx.innerHTML = "As you wander through the garden grounds you notice a striking Yellow Rose";

    }

  }
}
```

```css
.open{
  visibility:visible !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="yellowrose"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/ppfhZa6.jpg" style="visibility:hidden"></div>
<button id="showmore">Show More</button>
<div id="content">
content
</div>
```